# RDLC and Visual Studio 2022

Tags: rdlc, visual-studio-2022

We started using Visual Studio 2022, but after few days we'v got this terrible news:
VS2022 doesn't support RDLC designer.

Is there a workaround?
Sure we can continue to use VS2019 in parallel, but it's too uncomfortable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, we have just found this thread:

[Developer Community Visual Studio RDLC design in 2022](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/microsoft-rdlc-report-designer-in-2022/1494593)

We'll keep it monitored, but at the moment they don't have release a new tool.
A workaround seem to be this (quoted in the link above):

> A workaround until the designer is officially supported is to download Microsoft Report Builder and use it in editing your reports, Demo: https://youtu.be/3Wss8bvzjiE

**EDIT:**
Released for 2022!

[image]

Comment: [Link to marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022)

Comment: any possible rdlc designer on Mac

Comment: @Sras I think no... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/is-visual-studio-2019-for-mac-support-rdlc-report/1194517